# Reading from console input

Tags: android, linux, embedded-linux

Here is a weird hardware setup that I have got from someone:

- There is a receiver module that receives data wirelessly via some RF modulation. The module has a uart interface which it uses to send out the received data.
- There is an Android tablet. The tablet has exposed a built-in uart connector. If we connect it to a PC's COM port, we can get the Linux console of the tablet (with console input working)
- Now, the receiver module's uart is connected to the tablet's uart connector. Therefore, the received data will be sent to the console as input.

Here is the question: I would like to write an application (either native or dalvik-based), running on the tablet, to read the received data (which is being sent to the linux console as input). Can this be done?

I do not have the kernel source or binary, though I have the adb root access.

Comment: Of course!  The RF connection is external to the tablet; it does not matter to the console.  If you know how to write an app that reads/writes to stdin/stdout, and can execute that app from the console, then "yes".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is that I don't know how to execute my app from the console. I only have an adb shell.

Comment: You could try an open of the Linux console device by its *tty* name, e.g. `open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR)`